# Как найти зависимые экземпляры классов в дамп-файле с помощью библиотеки Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime

Tags: c#

Как найти зависимые экземпляры классов в дамп-файле. У кучи есть метод heap.EnumerateRoots(). Возвращает коллекцию созданных экземпляров, а как можно установить связи между этими экземплярами? 
Т.е. интересует не просто наследование одного класса от другого, а например, что элемент входит в коллекцию другого класса. Или является свойством и прочее.

Comment: Экземпляры можно перебирать и таким методом heap.EnumerateObjectAddresses(), но там тоже нет намека на зависимости с другими классами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение тут https://dzone.com/articles/traversing-gc-heap-clrmd. Дописал для полной ясности.

```
using (var dataTarget = DataTarget.LoadCrashDump(dmpFile))
{
    var runtime = dataTarget.ClrVersions[0].CreateRuntime();
    var heap = runtime.GetHeap();
    foreach (var clrRoot in heap.EnumerateRoots())
    {
        var stack = new Stack<ulong>();
        stack.Push(clrRoot.Object);
        var hashSet = new HashSet<ulong>(); 
        DisplayRefChainIfReachedObject(clrRoot.Object, clrRoot, stack, hashSet);
    }
}

static void DisplayRefChainIfReachedObject(ulong objPtr, ClrRoot root, Stack<ulong> refChain, HashSet<ulong> visited)
{
    ulong currentObj = refChain.Peek();
    if (visited.Contains(currentObj)) return;
    visited.Add(currentObj);
    ClrType type = heap.GetObjectType(currentObj);
    type.EnumerateRefsOfObject(currentObj, (innerObj, fieldOffset) =>
    {
        refChain.Push(innerObj);
        DisplayRefChainIfReachedObject(objPtr, root, refChain, visited);
        refChain.Pop();
    });
}
```

Получается от корневых объектов процесса, получим полный граф зависимостей всех экземпляров классов, созданных в процессе и сохраненных в дампе.